# Separate columns in a df with first and last date of a purchase for an email in python?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have some columns with emails and the saledates when they made their purchase and another column with valability of the purchase(12,24,36 months). how can I do to have separate columns for each email with his first and last purchase having also the valability unmodified?

So far I tried to separate in a new df, but had some errors on slicing.

```
first = df.groupby('Email').agg({'SaleDate': lambda x: x.min()})
last  = df.groupby('Email').agg({'SaleDate': lambda x: x.max()})
```

Did not work quite well and I had no clue how to incoporate the valability in a separate column.

LE: when I try to put

```
first = df.groupby('Email').agg({'SaleDate': lambda x: x.min(),'productvariation_months': lambda x: x})
```

to have a column near with validity I get this

```
Exception: Must produce aggregated value
```

Comment: What was the error? Share sample input and output data!!

Comment: Output is that the new column had NaT and the error is: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of data we can work on?